# How to handle duplicate firebase app initialisation

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am new to NextJS (and SSR in general) and noticed that I was getting the following error when Firebase is configured.

```js
//original code
import app from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/performance"
import "firebase/functions"
import "firebase/auth"
import "firebase/firestore"
import "firebase/analytics"

const config = {
  ...load config
}

const firebase = app.initializeApp(config)
export default firebase
```

```js
//error
Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists
```

I now understand this is due to the code attempting to set up Firebase twice. There is a [thread on Github](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/1999) that proposed a few similar solutions, such as the below.

```js
import * as firebase from "firebase"
import "firebase/performance"
import "firebase/functions"
import "firebase/auth"
import "firebase/firestore"
import "firebase/analytics"

const config = {
  ...load config
}

const firebaseApp = !firebase.apps.length ? firebase.initializeApp(config) : firebase.app()

export default firebaseApp
```

However, this new code has a new issue which is Firebase giving me the following warning:

```
It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK. When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import the individual SDK components you intend to use.
```

Is there a way of checking if there is already a Firebase app initialised without importing the entire library?

Comment: Just remove `import app from "firebase/app"` and or `import * as firebase from "firebase"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that works. You can check the apps initialised via `firebase/app`.

```
//original code
import firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/performance"
import "firebase/functions"
import "firebase/auth"
import "firebase/firestore"
import "firebase/analytics"

const config = {
  ...load config
}

const firebaseApp = firebase.apps.length ? firebase : firebase.initializeApp(config)

export default firebaseApp
```